# Existance of $\phi \in L^2$ such as $L(\vec v)=\int_{\Omega}\phi \;\text{div} \vec v \;dx$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, stokes-theorem

[I was working on Stokes pde, and I'm stuck in proving this, couldn't find it anywhere]

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^N$ an open bounded connected set such as $\partial \Omega$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$.

And we define $$V=\{\vec v \in (H^1_0(\Omega))^N; \text{div} \vec v=0\}$$
With $\text{div} \vec v=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}$.

I'm stuck in proving : if $L$ is a linear continious form on $(H_0^1(\Omega))^N$ such as $L_{|V}=0$ then there exists a function $\phi \in L^2(\Omega)$, such as $$\forall \vec v\in (H_0^1(\Omega))^N : L(\vec v)=\int_{\Omega}\phi \;\text{div} \vec v \;dx$$

My idea : I proved that $V$ is a closed space of $(H_0^1(\Omega))^N$ then its a Hilbert space, and I tried to apply Riesz 's theorem, but ut doesn't work.

Comment: $L$ is a function of $\text{div} v$ since it maps those $v$ with the same div to the same value. Now the space of all $\text{div} v$ is a subspace $E\subset L^2$, and $L$ is  linear and bounded on $E$, so by Hahn-Banach then by Riesz there is $\phi\in L^2$ so that for all $u\in E$ we have $L(u)=\int \phi u$, note $u=\text{div} v$.

Comment: I get the idea, but I m not convinced, because saying that $L $ is a function of $div \vec v $ (to me) does not make sense, because we suppose at beginning that $L$ is defined on $(H_0^1(\Omega))^N$(note that this is a product space), and $div \vec v$ is not a vector!

Comment: Actually I mean there is $F$ so that $L(v)=F(\text{div} v)$, and $F$ is linear, bounded on $L^2$, etc. as argued above......

Comment: Are you aware that you are asking about the de Rham lemma? You can find it in most literature on the mathematical theory of the (Navier-)Stokes equations, e.g. [this book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781461459743).

Comment: I Didn't know, I will check the book, thank you